# How can I get a new OAuth access token from an external provider

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

**I am trying to** renew my external providers OAuth access tokens after they expire. They are stored in my SQL database via the signin manager once the user has logged in using the external provider originally.

The access token is used by the server to make requests on the users behalf (mostly to update my database with some external providers information every now-and-then).

**I am using** a .NETCore 3 preview-6 Angular starter project with built-in Identity Server (I realize this a preview - but I think my issue is more related to a lack of understanding what I should be doing!). I haven't had too much trouble getting the original external login working (using `.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth(...)`).

But when my service that is using the provided access token gets a 401 response, I cannot figure how to get my server to renew the access token for the user silently.

**I have tried** using `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "MyScheme")]` on my Controller but this has the external provider responding with a CORS error. I then tried `HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(...)` in my service, but that just didn't even seem to work at all (maybe this is related to the preview version of .NETCore?).

I have even tried to re-create the scaffolded code that returns a `new ChallengeResult(...)`, but I get the same CORS error when called from my API. (I am unsure what black-magic is going on here to make the request appear like the referrer is the external provider.)

**TL;DR** (code snippet)

**Ideally**, I am trying to make the `// TODO` section work:

```cs
// This code is inside a Service I have which is called by a Controller action
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User);
var accessToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "MyScheme", "access_token");
_client.SetBearerToken(accessToken);

var response = await _client.GetAsync($"{uri}?{_query.ToString()}");
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)    // Just assuming 401 for simplicity
{
    // TODO: renew the access token and try again
}
```

I am expecting to get an updated access token back that I can use to re-do the request. Ideally this would be a silent renew, or a redirect if the requested external access has changed.

Hope this makes sense, please let me know if you need more information.

**Thanks**

Comment: if your external provider supports refresh tokens, you can use something like `var refreshToken = await _userManager.GetAuthenticationTokenAsync(user, "MyScheme", "refresh_token");` and then: var tokenResult = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest{
        Address = <https://external-idp/token>, ClientId = "<id@external>", ClientSecret = "secret", RefreshToken = refreshToken });` (you'll need Identity lib for `HttpClient` extensions)

Comment: @d_f thanks for your reply and suggestion. But, unfortunately the provider does not support refresh tokens. However - that would be a great solution for anyone else who might be stuck on this and their provider does.

Comment: Then only redirect would work for you. CORS blocks only xhr requests from script. You should redirect your whole page, or an IFrame, then it should work.